# Load external url in jquery dialog always show status cancelled

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to display a instagram login window in a jquery dialog:

```
$(function(){
            //$("#modal").dialog({ autoOpen: false });
            var url = "https://instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=http://www.google.com/&response_type=code";
            $("#modal").load(url).dialog({modal:true}); 
        });
```

The url works in the browser, but when I try to load in an iframe or dialog, doesn't works.
THe url not is the problem, because, I try with others URL, but in the chrome Network always show me Url -> Status cancelled

Comment: Look up same origin policy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating the dialog after the load is complete

```
$("#modal").load(url, function(){$(this).dialog({modal:true})});
```

Also for ajax [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) applies, so that might be a reason.

Comment: Always, show me the same message, status cancelled. In the documentation doesn't specify the status cancelled

Comment: @BenjaminDiaz if instagram doesn't support cross origin resource sharing, then you would get an error due to same origin policy. I believe this is the case since I saw no CORS headers when I went to that url.